# Create a set of boxes along with their connection by parsing a file using python

Tags: python

I have a file:

```
    class building1 ;
.....
.....
.....
    endclass

    class building2 ;
.....
.....
.....
    endclass



    class building3 ;
.....
.....
.....
endlcass


    class INSTRASTRUCTURE ;
building1 A; building2 B;  building3 C;

endclass


    class C;

A a;
B b;

a.connection(b);

endclass
```

I want to create a pictorial represenatation of `INFRASTRUCTURE`, which has building A,B,C (smaller boxes. Now inside the box C  , a is connected to b , so the code should read that  and create a line to show connection between a and b.How can I achieve this?

Comment: please structure your code and show an example of what you have done. it is hard to help otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

Making it as simple as possible, i use graph visualisation with svg, like:
import graphviz as gv

```
def to_svg_node_list(node_list, folder = 'img' , name = 'g2', fn = str):
g = gv.Digraph(format='svg')

for node in node_list:
    g.node(fn(node))  

for node in node_list:            
    for child in node.children:
        g.edge(fn(node), fn(child))

g.render(folder + '/' + name)
```

where :`node_list = [a,b] # your structures`,
define your oen **str** method inside of classes or define you own string representation of them.

each structure has children field, like you d have  a.connection(b) means

```
a.children = [b]
```

this would produce svg file like :

```
digraph {
    a-> b
... etc
```

what can be opened in browser.